# show/hide an listView on a buttonClick

Tags: android, listview, buttonclick

```
final ImageView patientAllergyImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
patientAllergyImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        patientAllergyImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().
                getDrawable(R.drawable.nav_down_green));
        List.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

I am making my List to Hide, but how do i show it when i click on the same button. I am not able to keep a boolean to check whether its clicked or not as it saying... `The final local variable clicked cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type` neither an `non` `final` variable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
     public void onClick(View V){
        patientAllergyImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().
                getDrawable(R.drawable.nav_down_green));
        List.setVisibility(List.isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of typical button, you can use a [toogle Button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) to achieve this

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // hide the listview
        } else {
            // show the listview
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       patientAllergyImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().
          getDrawable(R.drawable.nav_down_green));

       if(List.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
          List.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
       }else{
          List.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
       }
    }
```

Replace INVISIBLE by GONE if needed. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `final` for boolean variable or 
try this

try this

```
       if(List.getVisibility()==View.GONE)
        {
             List.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if(List.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
        {
             List.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there are a few issues here.

First of all you shouldn't call your listview "List" this is masking the real class called List.

1. Best to use "listView" with a lowercase "l" if you are stuck for a decent variable name.
2. You don't need to use final everywhere.
3. Use setImageResource instead to keep you code clean and readable.
4. Use the ?true:false syntax when it is readable

   ```
   ImageView patientAllergyImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
   patientAllergyImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

     //see if the list view is visible
     bool bVisible = listView.getVisibility();

     //select the image resource
     int iImageRes = bVisible?R.drawable.nav_down_green:R.drawable.nav_up_green;

     //Toggle Image
     (ImageView)v.setImageResource(iImageRes);

     //Toggle List Visibility
     listView.setVisibility(bVisible?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);

     }

   });
   ```